# .htaccess | Vanity URL's causing manually set $_GET variables to not take effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have htaccess rewrite mods to use vanity url's. I am trying to manually pass a $_GET variable to a login page telling people the login failed, but because of the vanity URL, the manually passed $_GET variable is being ignored.  How do I fix this?

Here is what I am trying to pass,

```
http://mysite.com/login?failed=1
```

But the only way for it to work is to do the following,

```
http://mysite.com/?p=login&failed=1
```

Which creates an obviously uglier effect.

My htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ncms/admin
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ncms/admin
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- Trick is to use QSA (Query String Append) flag to append `p=login` to existing query string
- As you can see your 2 rules can be combined into one as I sugested